# Git: Combining two independent repos to one without losing the history

Tags: git, github, configuration-management

I got two repos with the following folder structure:

```
> folder1
  >.git
  > file1
  > file2

> folder2
  >.git
  > file3
  > file4
```

Now I want to create a new repo combining the two formerly independent root folders under one common root:

```
> repo
   >.git
   > folder1
      > file1
      > file2
    > folder1
      > file3
      > file4
```

How would I do that in Git without losing the history of either formerly independent repository?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you merge two Git repositories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1425892/how-do-you-merge-two-git-repositories)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess something as follows should work:

1. Adapt the repo `folder1` to have the right internal structure.

   ```
   cd folder1
   mkdir folder1
   git mv file1 folder1/file1
   git mv file2 folder1/file2
   git commit -a
   ```
2. And ditto for the repo `folder2`.

   ```
   cd folder2
   mkdir folder2
   git mv file3 folder2/file3
   git mv file4 folder2/file4
   git commit -a
   ```
3. Pull one into the other one with `git pull`

   ```
   cd folder1  # the top one, not the one we have created in the 1st step.
   git pull /path/to/folder2
   ```

   Or, alternatively, merge both into a newly created repo.

   ```
   mkdir repo
   cd repo
   git init
   git pull /path/to/folder1
   git pull /path/to/folder2
   ```

Comment: I get "not something we can merge" when I try this with one of my existing repos.

Comment: Ooops. You are right. Forry for the mystification. `git merge` is just for branches in single repo. I now tried with `git pull` and it seems to work. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can find a solution [here](https://saintgimp.org/2013/01/22/merging-two-git-repositories-into-one-repository-without-losing-file-history/).

Basically,

1. make a new repo
2. merge from one of your repos
3. move files
4. repeat